# Exception in MCS character in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have these errors when I run my Unity project. They are related to a MCS character. These error cause other components to break. For example SALSA Lip-sync was not working correctly because this error was affecting the BlendShapes that are used by SALSA.

Error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
MORPH3D.COSTUMING.CostumeItem.setLODLevel (Single lodlevel, Boolean broadcast_change)
MORPH3D.COSTUMING.CIhair.setLODLevel (Single lodlevel, Boolean broadcast_change)
MORPH3D.SERVICES.CostumeModel.SetItemLODLevel (Single level)
MORPH3D.M3DCharacterManager.SyncCurrentLODLevel (Single level)
MORPH3D.M3DCharacterManager.initCharacterManager (Boolean refresh)
MORPH3D.M3DCharacterManager.Start ()
```

Warning:

```
Unable to find first CoreMesh/LOD in costume item: ShortPonytailHair, your asset will likely break and not work
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
MORPH3D.COSTUMING.CostumeItem:DetectCoreMeshes()
MORPH3D.COSTUMING.CIhair:DetectCoreMeshes()
MORPH3D.M3DCharacterManager:DetectAttachedHair()
MORPH3D.M3DCharacterManager:initCharacterManager(Boolean)
MORPH3D.M3DCharacterManager:Start()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem turn up to be in one of the assets - the hair. The Mesh Type of the "C Ihair (script)" was incorrectly set to "body". It must be changed to "hair".